# Can someone check my proof?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Theorem: In a set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $E$ is bounded iff $\exists r > 0$  such that $|x|<r$ for all $x \in E$

Proof: Assume $\exists r>0$ and $r$ is the supremum.

$\Leftarrow$ 
Suppose for all $x\in E, |x|<r$. If this is true, $E$ is bounded and the supremum is $r$.

$\Rightarrow$
Assume $E$ is bounded. Suppose towards contradiction that $|x| > r$. Then, r is not the supremum, and $E$ is not bounded $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

Hence it must be that $\exists r > 0$  such that $|x|<r$ for all $x \in E$.
Q.E.D

Comment: E is bounded? What's E? A subset of $\Bbb{R}$? You should probably put that explicitly.

Comment: How are you defining bounded? Normally, a set E is bounded precisely when $\exists \ r > 0$ s.t. $\lvert x \rvert < r \ \forall \ x \in E$, which means there is nothing to prove - but then again, normal definitions of a supremum require the set to be bounded, else it has no meaning (supremums of unbounded sets do not exist).

Comment: Nice, but is there any way someone can help my proof become a better argument?

Comment: Kindly state your definition of the adjective "bounded". Without this, nobody can help. Your theorem is what most people take for a definition.

Comment: Is your definition of "bounded" that $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in E} |x| < \infty$?

Comment: In the statement of the theorem you say "bounded above", but elsewhere you say just "bounded". They mean different things; which one is intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is what you intend to prove.

*Let $E \subseteq \Bbb R$, E is bounded $\iff$ $\exists r \gt 0 $ such that $|x| \le r$ for each $x \in E$.*

The proof is simple enough. In fact you don't need to go anywhere near $sup (E)$.

$$|x| \le r \iff -r \le x \le r $$

$x \le r $ for every $x \in E \implies $ $E$ is bounded above. 
Similarly, $-r\le x$ for each $x \in E \implies $ $E$ is bounded below. Therefore since $\exists a, b \in \Bbb R$ such that $x \in E \implies a \le x \le b$, E is bounded in $\Bbb R$

**Issues with your argument:**

1. You can't assume there is a supremum for any set in $\Bbb R$. You can only assume thus if you know that the set $E$ is non-empty and if it is bounded above.
2. $|x| \gt r$ does not imply that $x \gt r$ for some $r$. Sup $(-\infty, 0) = 0$ but $|x| \gt 0 \ \ \forall x \in (-\infty, 0) $.
3. You've also assumed the existence of the supremum and justified it by showing that $|x| \lt r$, which as Eric Wong pointed out is quite fallacious.

I suggest you refer to your text and properly grasp the definitions of bounds and suprema. They are fairly intuitive concepts and must be understood in that form and not in an entirely abstract way for you to progress.

Comment: For Issue 2, why do you say that $|x|<r$ does not imply $x < r$?  The bigger issue seems to be the assertion that $|x| < r$ automatically makes $r$ somehow the supremum of $E$.

Comment: @Erick Wong: Yeah that didn't make any sense. Thanks for pointing the error out. Corrected..