# Show that a set of real numbers $E$ is bounded if and only if there is a positive number $r$ so that $|x| < r$ for all $x\in E$.

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Show that a set of real numbers $E$ is bounded if and only if there is a positive number $r$ so that $|x| < r$ for all $x \in E$.

This is my answer. Am I answering the question?

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose a set of real number $E$ is bounded. By the completeness Axiom, a nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound $r=\sup E$. Then,$|x| < r $ for all $x \in E$.

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose there is a $r>0$ so that $|x| < r$ for all $x \in E$. By the  definition of upper bounds, a number $r$ said to be an upper bound for $E$ if  $|x| < r $ for all $x \in E$.

Therefore, a set of real numbers $E$ is bounded.

I am not sure how to prove this, can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: It's not correct, consider $E = \{1, -2\}$. You need to consider upper and lower bounds.

Comment: *By definition* a set $E$ of real numbers is bounded  if there is an $r>0$ such that $|x|<r$ for all $x\in E$.

Comment: Similar questoin: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667940/can-someone-check-my-proof/668066#668066

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: That is *a* definition, but not the only one, and clearly not the one given to the OP.

Comment: What is the definition of 'bounded set' given to you?

Answer (score 3):

You're not quite done in either direction.

For the first, if the set of real numbers $E$ consists entirely of negative numbers, then $r\le0,$ and you've got a problem. Instead, consider $r=1+\max\{\sup E,-\inf E\}.$ (Why does this work?)

For the second, note that $|x|<r$ means that $-r<x<r.$ Also, a number $t$ is said to be an upper (respectively, lower) bound for $E$ if $x\le t$ (respectively, $x\ge t$) for all $x\in E.$ A set $E\subseteq\Bbb R$ is bounded if it is bounded above and below.